# If a Shinigami and a Human were to have a child, what would they be called?

Tags: bleach

Simply, you can call it a *Shinigami/Human Hybrid*, *Half Shinigami, Half Human.*

But if it were to have a proper name.  What would you call it?

Comment: I'd call it Bob.

Comment: What is the english word for Shinigami?

Comment: @AlessandroSanfilippo The dubbed version of Bleach called them Soul Reapers

Comment: They would be called "Parents".

Comment: Why, that would be a Shinigami-kun, of course...

Answer (score 2):

The answer seems to depend a lot on the mother and where she gives birth. For instance, we have this in the Manga (hinted in the anime and a pretty massive spoiler)

> Ichigo Kurosaki is the son of [Masaki Kurosaki](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Masaki_Kurosaki), a human Quincy, and [Isshin Kurosaki](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Isshin_Kurosaki), the former 10th squad captain of the Soul Society/Gotei 13, who was wearing a special gigai that allowed him to save Masaki from her inner hollow. As Ichigo is born in the human world to a human mother, he is human. It's not clear how "human" Isshin was at the time, since he does regain his powers as a Soul Reaper/Shinigami. It's also clear that Ichigo inherited both Quincy and Soul Reaper powers from his parents.

It's not clear how/if other normal gigais could change this equation, since it was stated that

> Rukia's specially made gigai was meant to turn her into a human over time

Presumably only humans can be produced (albeit ones with more spiritual pressure/sensitivity than normal humans)